# fundamental calculus theorem application

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm not sure about the use of the Theorem.
I have:

$$f(x)=\int_0^{x^2}(t-1)g(t)dt$$
I need the derivative of $f$. I know i have to apply the chain rules, but i'm not sure about the results.
My result is:
$$f'(x)=(4x*g(x^2))+((x^2-1)*g'(x^2))$$
Is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general form of the type of integral you have in your question is this:
$$ f(x) = \int_a^{b(x)} h(t)\, dt $$

The derivative of $f$ can be obtained by using the FTC and the chain rule:
$$ f'(x) = h(b(x)) \cdot b'(x)$$

In your specific case, you have:
$$ f(x) = \int_0^{\overbrace{x^2}^{\color{red}{b(x)}}} \underbrace{(t-1) g(t)}_{\color{red}{h(t)}} \, dt$$

(Note that I didn't highlight or emphasize $a=0$ because it's irrelevant, because it's a lower-limit constant.)

Therefore:
$$ f'(x) = h(b(x)) \cdot b'(x) = \underbrace{(x^2 - 1)g(x^2)}_{h(b(x))} \cdot \underbrace{2x}_{b'(x)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\int_0^{y(x)}(t-1)g(t)\space\text{d}t\right]=(y(x)-1)g(y(x))y'(x)$$

So:

$$f'(x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\int_0^{x^2}(t-1)g(t)\space\text{d}t\right]=2x(x^2-1)g(x^2)$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: $f'(x)=(x^2-1)g(x^2)(2x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The "Fundamental Theorem of Calculus" says that $\frac{d}{du}\int_a^u f(t)dt= f(u)$.  Combine that with the "chain rule":  if u is a function of x then $\frac{dF}{dx}= \frac{dF}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$. Here we are taking $u= x^2$ so that $\frac{du}{dx}= 2x$. Then $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{x^2} (t- 1)g(t)dt= \frac{d}{du}\int_a^u (t- 1)g(t)dt\frac{du}{dx}= (x^2- 1)g(x^2)(2x)$.